# Why do I get the error: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#a3518 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Tags: flutter

I constantly get this error:
"  RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#a3518 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize' "
when I run this code:

(What I need is to have the 'Container' before the 'FutureBuilder', and the 'RaisedButton' after it because the 'FutureBuilder' can run multiple times, and I need just ONE container and ONE RaisedButton).

Please help me out!

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          'OrderLunch',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 26.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 595,
        width: 800,///not accurate
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/portocale.jpg'),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 3.5,
                  color: Colors.blue[400],
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              //padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              //color: Colors.white,
              child: Text(
                'copil/copii:',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 23.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: getMethod(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                List snap =  snapshot.data;

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('Error fatching Data'),
                  );
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snap.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text('         '),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    width: 4,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(4),
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  "${snap[index]['elevNume']} ${snap[index]['elevPrenume']}:",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 22.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text('         '),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    width: 4,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(4),
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Ii se va comanda maine mancare:',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 17.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text('  '),
                              _buildFirstDate(),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 300.0),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.blue[400],
              child: Text(
                'Save changes',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 19.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: (){
                updateMethod();
                if(b==1){
                  Text(
                    'Changes have been successfully saved!!',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  );
                  print(':)');
                  b=0;
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when I run this one I get no errors:

(But like I've said before, this is not what I need because the 'FutureBuilder' can run multiple times, but I don't want my 'Container', and my 'RaisedButton' to be shown more then one time)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          'OrderLunch',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 26.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 595,
        width: 800,///not accurate
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/portocale.jpg'),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
        ),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getMethod(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            List snap =  snapshot.data;

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Error fatching Data'),
              );
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snap.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            width: 3.5,
                            color: Colors.blue[400],
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        //padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        //color: Colors.white,
                        child: Text(
                          'copil/copii:',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 23.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text('         '),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                width: 4,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(4),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "${snap[index]['elevNume']} ${snap[index]['elevPrenume']}:",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 22.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text('         '),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                width: 4,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(4),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              'Ii se va comanda maine mancare:',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 17.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text('  '),
                          _buildFirstDate(),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 300.0),
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.blue[400],
                        child: Text(
                          'Save changes',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 19.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){
                          updateMethod();
                          if(b==1){
                            Text(
                              'Changes have been successfully saved!!',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                              ),
                            );
                            print(':)');
                            b=0;
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're trying to use `ListView.builder` in a `FutureBuilder` which has no sizes in a `Column`, so you need to constrain it somehow – either with `SizedBox(height: 300, child: ListView.builder())` or with `Expanded` widget

Check out this article https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrey Gritsay!

Comment: You're welcome! You could just mark my answer as a solution :)

Answer (score 6):

consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
so inside the ListView.builder widget ,add the shrinkWrap property as true.

```
ListView.builder(
  
   shrinkWrap: true, ///////////////////////Use This Line 

 )
```